# Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters; using Nodejs and Express server

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

I did not edit my blog successfully for this error. In my project this type of editing text comes one more time, firstly when I edited the text already store in MongoDB did not receive that error but today I repeated the same kind of code into my blog section  and getting error like follwing>>

[image]

after seeing this error I went to see similar work that has done before without error one more time that is it now having any issue and run/ edit text of the previous section of the project but seeing same error what I now facing actually It did work earlier but now why this comes do not understand

here is blog_edit.ejs file

```
<form action="/admin/blog/<%=post._id%>/edit" method="post" >


                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Categories</label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" name="category_id">
                            <option selected>Open this select category</option>
                            <% categories.forEach(function(category){ %>

                                <option value="<%=category._id%>"><%=category.name%></option>

                            <%})%>


                          </select>

                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleFormControlInput2">Title :</label>
                        <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput2"  value="<%=post.title%>">

                      </div>



                      <div class="form-group">
                        <textarea id="editor1" name="content" rows="10" cols="80"> <%=post.content%>"</textarea>
                      </div>


                      <div class="form-group">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="tags" value="<%=post.tags%>">
                      </div>


                      <div class="form-group">
                          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Update Blog Post</button>
                      </div>

                </form>
```

here is the middleware/rouer.js file

```
router.get('/admin/blog/:id/edit',  serverController.isAuthenticated, serverController.blog_edit)
router.post('/admin/blog/:id/edit',  serverController.isAuthenticated, serverController.blog_edit_post)
```

here also I have a controller file as serverController.js

```
exports.blog_edit = async function(req,res){
  res.render('server/blog_edit',{
    post : await blogCollection.findOne({_id : objectId(req.params.id)}),
    categories : await categoryCollection.find().toArray()
  })
}


exports.blog_edit_post = async function(req,res){
  let post = new Blog(req.body, req.file, req.params.id)

  post.edit().then(async()=>{
    res.redirect('/admin/blog')
  }).catch(()=>{
    res.send('404')
  })
}
```

Here the last I have is my model of this section as Blog.js

```
const blogCollection = require('../db').db().collection('blogs')
const objectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID




const Blog = function(blog, cover,id){
    this.blog = blog
    this.image = cover
    this.id = id
}



Blog.prototype.edit = function(){
    return new Promise(async(resolve,reject)=>{
        await blogCollection.updateOne({_id : objectId(this.id)}, {$set : {
            category_id : objectId(this.blog.category_id),
            title: this.blog.title,
            content : this.blog.content,
            tags : this.blog.tags,
            updated_at: date.getFullYear()+'-'+(date.getMonth()+1)+'-'+date.getDate()+'-'+date.getHours()+":"+date.getMinutes()+":"+date.getSeconds()

        }})
        console.log(this.blog)
        resolve()
})
}
```

if I make changes in `Blog.js` that I called Model of this blog section like following ->>

```
category_id : objectId(this.id.category_id),
```

instead of

```
category_id : objectId(this.blog.category_id)
```

then this problem is fixed but I did not see category name in the client page

like follwing, it comes blank after editing

[image]

Comment: What line of code does that error come from?  I also note that your code is missing some error handling.  There is not a single `try/catch` to catch any rejections around any of your `await` statements.

Comment: await blogCollection.updateOne({_id : objectId(this.id)}, {$set : {
            category_id : objectId(this.blog.category_id),

See this 2 lines